# This should not be happening. Outlook addin can't find assembly reference?? Why?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I can not work this out.  I have a class library called 'ABC.Service'. In this class library I have referenced other projects from my solution.

In my 'ABC.Service' I have consistently named my classes namespace 'ABC.Service'.

I have made a project reference to this 'ABC.Service' and another class library called 'ABC.Entities' from a OutlookAddin project in the same solution.

For some reason the outlook addin project does not compile and outputs that `'The type or name 'Service' does not exist in the namespace 'ABC' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` . However it does not complain about the 'ABC.Entities' classes???

The 'ABC.Service' compiles just fine and can be referenced successfully from a Windows project in the same solution which compiles just fine.

In the outlook addin intellisense can detect the namespace and class just fine also

I am obviously not missing the reference so the error message is so misleading.

I have tried;

- Cleaning project/solution
- Shutting down VS2010
- Restarting Computer

I can only see 2 possible problems (which I can not understand why they would be problems)

- In the 'ABC.Service' I have a
  reference to
  'Micorosoft.Office.Interop.Word'
  assembly.Could this be doing
  something?
- I have some generated code with a
  namespace called 'ABC.BusinessLogic'
  instead of 'ABC.Service' - removing
  this generated code to see if this is
  the problem would be a nightmare as
  much more would need to be changed to
  get it to compile and I really don't
  understand why it would be a problem

Has anyone got any ideas??

Any help appreciated

Comment: I've heard of this sort of thing happening when a project's build mode gets changed to "Client Profile." You might want to check on that.

Comment: You're a legend!! I changed the project properties away from 'Client Profile' like you said and that did it. If you put your answer in I can mark it as answered by you.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Please post as answer so this can be closed properly ;-)

Comment: @karusa, @pst: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard of this sort of thing happening when a project's build mode gets changed to "Client Profile." You might want to check on that.